# Vue set up IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, intersection-observer

I am trying to set up an IntersectionObserver for an infinite scroll list. I want to check with the IntersectionObserver if the last item of a list has been reached.

So far my **IntersectionObserver** setup looks like this:

```
mounted() {
    const config = {
        treshold: 1
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) console.log(entry.target);
        });
    }, config);

    observer.observe(this.lastRenderedDeal());
}
```

My **list items** are rendered like this:

```
<deal :deal="deal"
      :key="index"
      ref="deals"
      v-for="(deal, index) in deals"
</deal>
```

To fetch the last **renderedDeal** I use the `ref` on the deals:

```
lastRenderedDeal() {
    const deals = this.$refs.deals;
    return deals ? deals[deals.length - 1].$el : null;
}
```

This works for the initial setup and it triggers. The problem is that when I want infinite scroll I need to keep appending to the list of deals. So my `lastRenderedDeal` constantly updates to reflect the last deal that was appended to my list.

This reactivity is not being passed on to the `observer.observe` method it seems. It only picks up my initial element. This seems kind of obvious since it has been instantiated in the `mounted` hook but how can I deal with this?

Do I need to set a watcher for the deals and call the observer.observe again? If so, can I simply tell it to replace the initial observed item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can observe a dummy `<div>` which is always at the bottom of the list. You might need to set a `key` on the `<div>` to ensure that Vue won't recreate the element during each render of the component.

I always like to make a general and reusable component which bundles this behavior. Here's my take:

```js
const InfiniteScroll = {
  render(h) {
    return h('div', [
      ...this.$slots.default,

      // A dummy div at the bottom of the list which we will observe.
      // We must set a key on this element so that Vue reuses
      // the same element it initially created upon each rerender.
      h('div', {
        key: 'footer',
        ref: 'footer',
        style: {
          height: '1px'
        },
      }),
    ]);
  },

  mounted() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      // We only have one entry. Is it visible?
      if (entries[0].intersectionRatio > 0) {
        this.$emit('trigger');
      }
    });

    // Observe the dummy footer element
    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.footer);
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    InfiniteScroll,
  },
  data: {
    items: [],
  },
  created() {
    this.loadMore();
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        this.items.push(this.items.length + 1);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <infinite-scroll @trigger="loadMore">
    <div v-for="item of items" class="item">{{ item }}</div>
  </infinite-scroll>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fixed my issue by using a watcher with a `$nextTick` method that updates the observer like so: `this.observer.observe(element);` but I like your approach a lot more. It abstracts away the infinite scroll logic to it's own component. Love it, thanks for your help.

Comment: Also there might be a way to avoid the 1px height style; I tried playing with [`rootMargin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin) but it doesn't help (admittedly I didn't try too hard so someone might be able to suggest a fix for it).

Comment: upvoted! sorry if this is a stupid question, i dont understand what is happening, if you click inspect element, the number of nodes keep increasing so where exactly does the intersection observer recycle content while keeping only a few nodes around

Comment: @PirateApp This isn't meant to be a virtualized list; you don't get virtualization for free just by using an intersection observer. There are virtualized list implementations on GitHub I recommend you check out.